# Reactive design: throw vs. publish error

Tags: swift, try-catch, reactive-programming, rx-swift

The following code example has (Rx)Swift smell to it, but the question is generic to any language with reactive features and throwing capability.

Consider a function which returns an observable sequence, but it does some sanity checking prior to creating the sequence. Check failure means that the sequence can't produce values.

```
func yieldFoos() -> Observable<Foo> {
  guard isValid(internalFoo) else {
    // throw or return one shot observable?
  }
  return createValidObservable(from: internalFoo)
}
```

In case of state validity check failure, should the function throw or return one shot observable, which will ever produce just an error? My coder's guts came up with these pros and cons:

Throwing feels logically cleaner (it is a failure preventing observable creation), but results in cumbersome calling code - catch block, multiple error handling points in different execution scopes.

One shot observable results in shorter and cleaner calling code, but somehow feels wrong. The observable is forced to be a carrier for non sequential error state, for the sake of brevity.

Anyone having a strong opinion worth following? Or another overlooked, elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder about your feeling that it's wrong for an Observable to emit an error. That's part of it's job.

When you think about it, your `createValidObservable(from:)` function might emit an error despite being handed a valid internalFoo so the code that calls `yieldFoos()` has to be prepared to handle an emitted error anyway. You might as well roll all your error handling code together. I would go further and make your create function able to handle invalid foos itself by emitting an error and doing away with this yieldFoos function.

Now, if you want `yieldFoos()` to return a `Driver` rather than an observable, *then* you have to handle the error through throwing or a precondition (because Drivers don't emit errors.)

```
func yieldFoos() -> Observable<Foo> {
    guard isValid(internalFoo) else {
        return Observable.error(myError)
    }
    return createValidObservable(from: internalFoo)
}
```

I think you need to get over your feeling that having an Observable that immediately returns an Error is wrong. That is a perfectly valid thing for an Observable to do and something all code using that Observable needs to be ready to handle.

Comment: It's not wrong that Observable emits an error. I just feel that such error should be "of the observable" (inability to continue the sequence), not of creating the observable in the first place. Sequence failure is normal, creation failure is an exceptional inconsistency, hence throwing seemed appropriate. But the existence of single shot `Observable.error` operator hints that i may be just thinking too much.

Comment: If your create function was handed an invalid internalFoo, it would be unable to continue the sequence... :-) It may help to think of the Observable error as their version of throw, or think of it as a throw for asynchronous events. It works like a throw in that it propagates through the pipe until it's handled...

Comment: so would you put it this way - in a reactive code, there is less use cases for throwing in general? I think that one of the key reactive concepts is that everything could be gradually asynchronous and even lazy, but your transformation code shouldn't care. Whereas throwing is inherently synchronous...

Comment: No, that's not quite right... I'm saying that Rx's onError event is analogous to a throw. For example if you throw inside a `flatMapLatest` or any other Rx operator, it will automatically be converted into an `onError` event. Exceptions and Error events are two different ways to represent the same abstraction. Yes, throwing is synchronous, but but so are error events in that they will immediately shut down a observable chain.

Comment: @PavelZdenek I see the distinction you clarified regarding creation failure to a sequence failure. What do you think about distinguishing them by throwing an error of the creation of the Observable and emitting an error (respectively)? That is, `yieldFoos() throws -> Observable<Foo>`, wherein if it fails to create the observable, an error is thrown. However, if there are errors in the observable sequence, then it is terminated with the onError event. That way the creation of the observable's error can be distinguished from the sequence errors.

Comment: That means handling the error for the creation of the observable would be handled within the local scope of the closure (i.e. `flatMap`) that calls `yieldFoos()` because it will demand that you handle it via the `do-try` syntax. On the other hand, if you stick with emitting a single error to stop the whole sequence, you'll have greater control or more options on which parent observable can handle this error using the `catchError` operator (better dependency inversion) compared to the local scope for the standard `do-try` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be something like this:

```
func yieldFoos() -> Observable<Foo> {
    Observable.create { observer in 

        guard isValid(internalFoo) else {
            observer.onError(yourError)
        }

        let subscription =  
            createValidObservable(from: internalFoo)
                .subscribe(onNext: { foo in
                    observer.onNext(foo)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                })
        return Disposables.create {
            // your dispose
            subscription.dispose()
        }
    }

}
```

And then, when you call it:

```
yieldFoos()
    .subscribe(
     onNext: { foo in
         // your code with foo
     },
     onError: { error in
        // manage errors
     })
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: I know how to construct and use observables, thank you. I am asking whether exceptional failures should be thrown or put to sequence. You seem to favor sequences, but without reasoning.